# integration of $\sqrt{4x+9}/\sqrt{4x+8}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

When I use the online integral calculator (http://www.integral-calculator.com), there are five total methods (all $u$-substitution).

I manage to do the last couple out by hand but I was wondering how long/complicated would $u = \dfrac{\sqrt{4x+9}}{\sqrt{4x+8}}$ substitution be.

Comment: Why don't u try without wondering?

Comment: Because it is cool how it all worked itself out.

Comment: This site is for **real questions**, on which people are blocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$I = \int \frac{\sqrt{4x+9}}{\sqrt{4x+8}}\,dx$$

Let $$u = \frac{\sqrt{4x+9}}{\sqrt{4x+8}}\implies (4x+8)u^2=4x+9$$

$4x(u^2-1) = 9-8u^2 \implies x = \frac{9-8u^2}{4(u^2-1)}$

Then $$du = \frac{\sqrt{4x+8}\cdot \frac{1}{2}\cdot 4\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{4x+9}}-\sqrt{4x+9}\cdot 4 \cdot \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{4x+8}}}{4x+8}dx$$

$$du =\frac{\frac{2\sqrt{4x+8}}{\sqrt{4x+9}} -\frac{2\sqrt{4x+9}}{\sqrt{4x+8}}}{4x+8}dx=\frac{2(4x+8)-2(4x+9)}{(4x+8)\sqrt{(4x+9)(4x+8)}}dx = $$

$$du = -\frac{2}{(4x+8)\sqrt{(4x+9)(4x+8)}}dx$$

$$\require{cancel}I = -\frac{1}{2}\int  \frac{\sqrt{4x+9}}{\sqrt{\cancel{4x+8}}}\cdot (4x+8)\sqrt{(4x+9)\cancel{(4x+8)}}\, du $$

$$I = -\frac{1}{2}\int(4x+9)(4x+8)\,du$$

substituting in $u$ for $x$:

$$\require{cancel}I = -\frac{1}{2}\int \bigg(\cancel{4}\cdot \frac{9-8u^2}{\cancel{4}(u^2-1)}+9\bigg)\bigg(\cancel{4}\cdot \frac{9-8u^2}{\cancel{4}(u^2-1)}+8\bigg)du$$

$$I = -\frac{1}{2}\int \bigg(\frac{9-8u^2+9u^2-9}{u^2-1}\bigg)\cdot\bigg(\frac{9-8u^2+8u^2-8}{u^2-1}\bigg)du$$

$$I = -\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{u^2}{u^2-1}\cdot \frac{1}{u^2-1}\,du$$

Now this can be solved by using another substitution or by partial fractions - although this is a very inefficient method for solving the original integral.

Comment: Which method would you have done?

Answer (score 0):

If you do the proposed substitution, you get
$$
x=\frac{9-8u^2}{4(u^2-1)}
$$
so
$$
dx=\frac{1}{4}\frac{-16u(u^2-1)-2u(9-8u^2)}{(u^2-1)^2}\,du=
-\frac{1}{2}\frac{u}{(u^2-1)^2}\,du
$$
so the integral becomes
$$
-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{u^2}{(u^2-1)^2}\,du
$$
A standard partial fraction decomposition will end the job.

Answer (score 0):

Let 4x+8 = u, then 4dx=du, hence (1/4)Int\sqrt(1+1/u)du

now Int\sqrt(1+1/u)du = sqrt(1 + 1/u) u + 1/2 log((2 sqrt(1/u + 1) + 2) u + 1) + constant = *

Ans. (1/4)*